# Adding a date and the time portion of a datetime2 together

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a date field [`load_date`] and a datetime2 field [`load_time`] that I want to combine into a datetime2.  I want to combine `load_date` with the time portion of `load_time` and create a datetime2.

It's in an existing table, and I want to `SET` the `load_time` to this new value.  Below is a `SELECT` that appears to work, so I can turn this into an `UPDATE` statement.  However, I wanted to know if there is a more elegant or less verbose way.

```
SELECT
    [load_date]
    , [load_time]
    , DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(CAST([load_time] AS TIME) AS DATETIME2), CAST([load_date] AS DATETIME2)), CAST(CAST([load_time] AS TIME) AS DATETIME2))
```

Comment: please show some sample data and the expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT` and rely on implicit conversion to do it less verbosely.  Both queries use 0 CPU, so you may have to run a lot of iterations to see if one is significantly more efficient than the other.

```
SELECT 
    [load_date], 
    [load_time], 
    CONCAT([load_date], ' ', CAST([load_time] AS TIME)) 
FROM [test_table_1]
```

You aren't *required* to explicitly convert it to DATETIME2 because it will be converted implicitly when it updates the load_time column.  Note that having the shortest code is not always the best.  Using comments to explain what the code is doing will prevent anyone from having to figure out what it's doing.